# Make a React app listen for keyboard input and call a function that has access to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener

New to React.

I'm trying to make it so my app is ready to respond to keyboard inputs (namely arrow buttons) from the get-go by setting up an eventListener.  Problem seems to be I don't know the right way to add that eventListener so that the function called can access the component's state.

Here's my function

```
handleKeyUp(event) {
    let retRow = this.state.retRow;
    let retCol = this.state.retCol;
    switch(event.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            retRow += -1;
            break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
            retRow += 1;
            break;
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            retCol += -1;
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            retCol += 1;
            break;
        default:
    }
    this.setState({retRow, retCol});
}
```

I tried putting it the outermost div of what gets rendered, but `this` seems to be undefined if I do that.

```
render() {
    /*...*/
    return (
        <div onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}>
            <h1>{headerText}</h1>
            {this.renderBoard(this.state.rowCount,this.state.colCount)}
            <button onClick={() => this.resetGame()}>Restart</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I tried putting it on the document when component mounts, but that makes `this` refer to `document`

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
}
```

}

Either way `this` is the wrong thing for me to be able to access the component's state with `this.state`.  How can I get my component to respond to keyboard inputs like I want?

Comment: Did you bind your `handleKeyUp` in the constructor? `this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)`

Comment: ```this.handleKeypUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)``` is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!